# How to remove github automated checks and deployment after uninstalling app

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I uninstalled the Vercel app from github, but it's still running checks and auto-deployment when I commit code or open a pull request.
How can I remove all the automated checks, environments, and deployments installed by the app? I thought that uninstalling the app would remove automations by default, but I guess that's not true. This is on a private repo.

Your help is appreciated!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who is still interested.
Go to your project settings on Vercel.

eg [https://vercel.com/{accName}/{project}/settings](https://vercel.com/%7BaccName%7D/%7Bproject%7D/settings)

On the left panel, click "git", you can disconnect from there.

[Vercel Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29jQx.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can disable Vercel's automated deployment checks by deleting the corresponding deployment environment.

However, 'Environments' are [only available in public repositories if you're **not** a GitHub Pro user](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment). If you're not a Pro user and are working with a private repository, the 'Environments' tab will not be visible to you.

In this case, follow these steps to disable Vercel's automated deployment checks:

1. Change repository visibility to public.[image]
2. Go to the 'Environments' tab that has become available in the settings.
3. Find the relevant environment and delete it.[image]
4. Change repository visibility to private again.

You will not encounter Vercel's automated deployment checks on your subsequent commits.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Github-repo** > **Settings** > **Environment**, and delete the environment you no longer need:

[image: example-img]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to delete vercel application in github settings. But no way.
I went to vercel and deleted the registered account from github.
You can try.

Answer (score 0):

1.Before Uninstalling you should check the Authentication settings which at **Setting>Authentication** disconnected Github from there.
2. For deleting your profile go to **Settings>General** and go bottom of the, there will be one option for delete the account. You can delete your account then you uninstall the app perfectly and safely.

Answer (score -1):

Check first if you still see workflows listed with your project.

You might need to [delete all their past run results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57927115/6309), in order for those to disapear.