# Can I delete a Github workflow run within the workflow itself?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

We developed a CI system that runs via Github actions on self-hosted runners.

In order to prevent building unnecessarily, we incorporated a pre-build job that triggers a build only if the commit message has `[trigger ci]` anywhere.

Now we are facing a slight annoyance: Even if the build job doesn't run, we still have a workflow run show up in the workflow runs list, as expected, but it has basically become a copy of the commit history and very hard to navigate or find which workflows did actually build.

Is there any way that I can delete a workflow run from the workflow runs list conditionally, within the workflow itself? This way, we can keep only the runs that did trigger a build, and delete the ones that skipped building.

Comment: You could use the [Github REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-runs#delete-workflow-run-logs) directly, or even a [Delete Workflow Runs](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/delete-workflow-runs) action from the marketplace. It's also possible using the GitHub CLI (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57927115/delete-a-workflow-from-github-actions)).

Comment: Possibly related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57927115/delete-a-workflow-from-github-actions